# Time's Arrow, or Why does time seem to be flowing in one direction?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, time, research-level, popular-science

I have been working on this topic for the past 6 months, and I Understand what is time, but why does it have a direction? Why was the Entropy low in the Early Universe? I have got success in some results and testable predictions. I've been very curious about this since my childhood and I am asking myself questions why does time has a direction? Why we can't travel to the past? and Defiantly about Time Travel. Now I am able to find those answers at least I am trying and get little success on that. Now, I want to publish my work in International Journal. But, I am a Student in 12 Grade. I don't have experience with Journals. And as I am 12 Grade Student I don't have any Affiliation too. I just want to know what is the best journal related to my Research? Can I Publish my Paper without any Affiliation? And is there any Journal where I can publish my paper for Free? Answers to these questions I am searching for right now. Help me to find those answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can publish on https://vixra.org. There you can publish without affiliation.

Comment: @JacopoTissino Where Can I ask this question to get a satisfactory answer?

Comment: The topic (journal choice) is in the domain of academia.stackexchange.com, but your question would probably be closed there as well since it's a shopping question (https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping). 
I'd second Habouz's advice: hold off on thoughts of publication until you have familiarized yourself with the state of the art in the field you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, time flows in one direction because the past affects the future and not the other way around, and if you want to affect the past, you have to move faster than light which we believe is impossible with current theories. Maybe a new theory might change things but for now, we assume it's impossible.

For your journal, I recommend you to wait until you have an affiliation. You can work on your theory and improve it. I would also recommend you to save your findings online but privately just so you can refer to them later on.

Comment: Okay. So My Focus in Journal is on that question. But we can make this discussion interesting by talking on time. Your Answer is not the Answer to my Research. The Main Question is Why Entropy was low in the early universe or we can also say this way why the universe begin with such low entropy?